# force Rscript to open plotly in browser viewer

Tags: r, htmlwidgets

I have the following code in `plot.R` file.

```
library(plotly)
options(browser = "/opt/google/chrome/chrome")
options(viewer = NULL)

plot_ly(economics, x = ~date, y = ~pce, z = ~pop) %>%
  htmlwidgets::onRender(
    "function(el, x) {
     var gd = document.getElementById(el.id); 
     Plotly.downloadImage(gd, {format: 'png', width: 600, height: 400, filename: 'plot'});
   }"
  )
```

Running this code from Rstudio or R console works as expected: svg image is saved in the downloads directory specified in chrome. However both `source('plot.R')` from RStudio or `Rscript plot.R` from console doesn't seem to open the browser and save the imgage. There is no error.

I need to be able to run this script using `Rscript` command.

UPDATE

Thanks to Krystian answer adding `print()` helped for Rstudio. However, I still can't get browser viewer open frm RScript.

Answer (score 1):

Just force `print` method on created plot:

```
plot_ly(economics, x = ~date, y = ~pce, z = ~pop) %>%
  htmlwidgets::onRender(
    "function(el, x) {
     var gd = document.getElementById(el.id); 
     Plotly.downloadImage(gd, {format: 'png', width: 600, height: 400, filename: 'plot'});
   }"
  ) %>% print
```

Comment: Thanks this works in RStudio, but unfortunatelly not when `Rscript plot.R`

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested to save the image rather than to see the browser open, the following script can help you: https://gist.github.com/anadiedrichs/68dbadd4135acc9a51ff8520a5cd987c

The example use the **webshot** library to do what you need.

1. You have to install plotly, webshot and htmltools packages
2. Run: `webshot::install_phantomjs()`
3. Use/modify the following script for your own needs.